# interp1 'next' appears to give 'nearest'

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have a series of z values `zk` and a temperature value `Tadjust0` at each `zk`. From this I'd like to create a series of steps of height `Tadjust0(j)` going from `zk(j-1)` to `zk(j)`.

I'm trying to achieve this with:

```
zk=[40.41; 50.04; 59.56; 68.95; 78.22; 87.40; 99.95];
Tadjust0=[-1.1500; 1.6033; 2.4287; 3.2430; 3.8500; 3.8500; 3.8500];
zo=[1:0.01:100];
Tadjust1=interp1(zk,Tadjust0,zo,'next','extrap');
figure
plot(zo,Tadjust1)
figure
scatter(zk,Tadjust0)
```

But as far as I can tell, the interpolation seems to be using 'nearest' rather than 'next': the steps don't end at `zk(j)`, they end at `(zk(j)+zk(j+1))/2`. In fact, if I change the code to 'nearest' I get exactly the same plots.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my R2016a installation.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem lies within the simultaneous use of next neighbour *interpolation* and *extrapolation*. You can separate the interpolation and extrapolation to be sure:

```
zk=[40.41; 50.04; 59.56; 68.95; 78.22; 87.40; 99.95];
Tadjust0=[-1.1500; 1.6033; 2.4287; 3.2430; 3.8500; 3.8500; 3.8500];
zo=[1:0.01:100];

% Nearest neigbour inter-/ extrapolation
Tadjust1=interp1(zk,Tadjust0,zo,'nearest','extrap');

% Get indices of zo within the range of zk
interp_range = zo > min(zk) & zo < max(zk);

% Replace the interpolated values by next neighbour interpolation
Tadjust1(interp_range)=interp1(zk,Tadjust0,zo(interp_range),'next');

figure
plot(zo,Tadjust1)
figure
scatter(zk,Tadjust0)
```

Raw data:
[image]
Result:
[image]